# Redmine + Ruby error: ActionView::Template::Error - undefined local variable or method `block'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

In Redmine we have the "My Page" show some stuff, including a `_issues.erb` page:

```
<div class="contextual">
  <%= link_to_function l(:label_options), "$('##{block}-settings').toggle();", :class => 'icon-only icon-settings', :title => l(:label_options) %>
</div>
```

but after a recent update of some plugins, it's no longer accepting this code, and in the logs we see

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `block' for #<#<Class:0x00007fd303e3a430>:0x00007fd2fc2b3e38>
Did you mean?  @blocks):
    1: <div class="contextual">
    2:   <%= link_to_function l(:label_options), "$('##{block}-settings').toggle();", :class => 'icon-only icon-settings', :title => l(:label_options) %>
    3: </div>
    4: 
    5: <h3>
```

In other places in the same template we see `block` used with only one `#`, would that be the correction? For example, not sure if there is also error on these lines, but they show the different `##` vs `#` use of the `block`:

```ruby
    <div id="<%= block %>-settings" style="display:none;">
      <%= form_tag(my_page_path, :remote => true) do %>
        <div class="box">
          <%= render_query_columns_selection(query, :name => "settings[#{block}][columns]") %>
        </div>
        <p>
          <%= submit_tag l(:button_save) %>
          <%= link_to_function l(:button_cancel), "$('##{block}-settings').toggle();" %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

What is going on and why would it fail now? The plugins didn't do anything to these pages, they are unchanged since before the upgrade.

Here are the version infos, if those help:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.4.6.stable
  Ruby version                   2.5.1-p57 (2018-03-29) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  4.2.11.3
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               PostgreSQL
```

Edit:

Here is the partial callstack and relevant code snips:

```
  app/views/my/blocks/_issues.erb:2:in `_app_views_my_blocks__issues_erb___4510516419606634452_70176136873380'
  app/helpers/my_helper.rb:133:in `render_issuequery_block'
  app/helpers/my_helper.rb:64:in `render_block_content'
  app/helpers/my_helper.rb:35:in `render_block'
  plugins/redmine_reporter/lib/redmine_reporter/patches/my_helper_patch.rb:19:in `render_block_with_reporter'
  ....
```

`/my_helper_patch.rb:19:in 'render_block_with_reporter'` :

```
def render_block_with_reporter(block, user)
          return '' if %w(report_by_issues report_by_spent_time).include?(block) && !user.allowed_to?(:view_time_entries, nil, global: true)

          render_block_without_reporter(block, user)  // Line 19
        end
```

`app/helpers/my_helper.rb:35:in 'render_block'` :

```
  # Renders a single block
  def render_block(block, user) 
    content = render_block_content(block, user) // Line 35
    if content.present?
      handle = content_tag('span', '', :class => 'sort-handle', :title => l(:button_move))
      close = link_to(l(:button_delete),
                      {:action => "remove_block", :block => block},
                      :remote => true, :method => 'post',
                      :class => "icon-only icon-close", :title => l(:button_delete))
      content = content_tag('div', handle + close, :class => 'contextual') + content

      content_tag('div', content, :class => "mypage-box", :id => "block-#{block}")
    end
  end
```

`app/helpers/my_helper.rb:64:in 'render_block_content'` :

```
# Renders a single block content
  def render_block_content(block, user)
    unless block_definition = Redmine::MyPage.find_block(block)
      Rails.logger.warn("Unknown block \"#{block}\" found in #{user.login} (id=#{user.id}) preferences")
      return
    end

    settings = user.pref.my_page_settings(block)
    if partial = block_definition[:partial]
      begin
        render(:partial => partial, :locals => {:user => user, :settings => settings, :block => block})
      rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
        Rails.logger.warn("Partial \"#{partial}\" missing for block \"#{block}\" found in #{user.login} (id=#{user.id}) preferences")
        return nil
      end
    else
      send "render_#{block_definition[:name]}_block", block, settings   // line 64
    end
  end
```

`app/helpers/my_helper.rb:133:in 'render_issuequery_block'` :

```
  def render_issuequery_block(block, settings)
    query = IssueQuery.visible.find_by_id(settings[:query_id])

    if query
      query.column_names = settings[:columns] if settings[:columns].present?
      query.sort_criteria = settings[:sort] if settings[:sort].present?
      issues = query.issues(:limit => 10)   // Line 132
      render :partial => 'my/blocks/issues', :locals => {:query => query, :issues => issues, :block => block, :settings => settings}
    else
      queries = IssueQuery.visible.sorted
      render :partial => 'my/blocks/issue_query_selection', :locals => {:queries => queries, :block => block, :settings => settings}
    end
  end
```

(I added the "wrong" comments of // line number for clarity).

Comment: Block with ## vs # will behave differently. # is like you are using block as variable vs string in other case. Not sure on the plugins part since there is not much info about that in question.

Comment: I can't understand why the "block" variable is undefined in this scope, I pasted the callstack and relevant code snipets into the question. Where would the block variable be lost from the scope, why isn't it working from render_issuequery_block line 133, it's defined in the call as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

So, we "fixed" this by just renaming the "block" variable to "something", in the last two call stack frames.

eg.

```
<div class="contextual">
  <%= link_to_function l(:label_options), "$('##{something}-settings').toggle();", :class => 'icon-only icon-settings', :title => l(:label_options) %>
</div>
```

and

```
render :partial => 'my/blocks/issues', :locals => {:query => query, :issues => issues, :block => block, :something => block}
```

Still have no idea what exactly caused this, but now it's no longer an issue and that's good enough for now.